# Parse On Buddy Logout User

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, buddy.com

I am migrating an application from parse.com to buddy.com. One of the caveats of the migration was that `Parse.User.current()` is no longer available on buddy.com, instead you have to get the user and session token from the request itself: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-Server/wiki/Compatibility-with-Hosted-Parse#no-current-user

The application I am migrating has a `logoutUser` method that I am attempting to migrate:

```
 Parse.Cloud.define("logoutUser", function(request, response) {
     Parse.User.logOut().then(
         function onSuccess(result){
             response.success(result);
         },
         function onError(error) {
            response.error(error);
         }
     )
 });
```

now I am attempting to do this in the new style, but am receiving an error. (NOTE: This is cloud code not a nodejs environment)

```
{ 
  "code":"500",
  "error":"Error: There is no current user user on a node.js server environment."
}
```

New implementation:

```
function logoutUser(request, response) {
    var user = request.user; 
    var sessionToken = user.getSessionToken();

    Parse.User.logOut({ sessionToken }).then(
        function onSuccess(result){
            response.success(result);
        },
        function onError(error) {
        response.error(error);
        }
    )
}

Parse.Cloud.define("logoutUser", function(request, response) {
    logoutUser(request, response);
});
```

Suggestions on how to correctly log out users in the Parse on Buddy cloud code?

Comment: Unsure what you're trying to do here.  Because there is no Current User on any cloud code environment,  they can't be logged out.  The solution suggesting to get the requesting user and session token is to pass the token when running any Parse.Query's. You don't have to log out a user in cloud code,  only on the local device/browser.

Comment: @EReid hmm ok, maybe I am misunderstanding then. I am new to Cloud Code and to this application specifically. So I guess this means that logout never worked in this app since the logout function was Cloud Code function.

Comment: @EReid When you say log out locally on the device, is that in any way related to parse? Or just to the app itself?

Comment: I'm not too sure of the details of how the `Parse.User` worked on the original Parse.com, so wouldn't really be able to comment on whether it ever worked. By logging out locally, it all depends on the SDK you're using. I know the Javascript SDK, and the Android SDK both have functions to log the user out respectively:`Parse.User.logOut()` and `ParseUser.logOut();`. If using the Rest api, you'll simply have to stop sending the `X-Parse-Session-Token` header, and delete the stored token.

Comment: Yeah we aren't using any SDKs for the web client, just POST and GET to the buddy.com endpoints. Thanks so much, this has been really helpful. I will happily mark your last comment as an answer if you'd care to move it down.

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch user's session or sessions and delete it / them:

```
   var query = new Parse.Query("_Session");
   query.descending('createdAt');
   query.equalTo('user', {__type:"Pointer", className:"_User", objectId:"idhere"});
     query.first({
     useMasterKey: true
   }).then(function(session) {
    var sessions = [];
    sessions.push(session);
    Parse.Object.destroyAll(sessions);
   }, function (err) {
      console.log("Internal error " + err);
   });
```

OR for more tokens you could use find instead of first like:

```
   var query = new Parse.Query("_Session");
   query.equalTo('user', {__type:"Pointer", className:"_User", objectId:"idhere"});
     query.find({
     useMasterKey: true
   }).then(function(sessions) {
    Parse.Object.destroyAll(sessions);
   }, function (err) {
      console.log("Internal error " + err);
   });
```

The above will mostly delete or tokens related to the given user. If you wish to delete only tokens used for login, and not for signup or upgrade, then you could put into your query:

```
query.equalTo('createdWith', { action: 'login', authProvider: 'password'});
```

As far as i know, deleting a user's last used for login token, then he is logged-out.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above, if you pass up the user's session key to the Cloud Code function via the X-Parse-Session-Token header, you can use the populated request.user object in the session query directly, instead of the user's ID.